# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ... on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, netbeans, dex2oat

I am making an android project game which I recently added some libraries to this project, and since I did I get the same error:

```
dex2oat : Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@***.*******.*************-2@base.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "***.*******.*************.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/***.*******.*************-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/***.*******.*************-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3132)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.compgal.stealthsmiley.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.compgal.stealthsmiley-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.compgal.stealthsmiley-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.compgal.stealthsmiley-1/base.apk
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:279)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makePathElements(DexPathList.java:248)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:120)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:86)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:47)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:438)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:663)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6395)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                ... 6 more
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ***.*******.*************.MainActivity
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:                ... 12 more
03-25 10:34:07.084 15904 15904 E AndroidRuntime:        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I believe I should say that all the projects / library projects are using the same target "android-23". I have checked all the answers on StackOverflow and other websites and could'nt find any answer that solved my problem.
Thanks for helping!

**EDIT**

The project is written on Netbeans IDE framework, not on android studio and the project isnt using gradle.
here is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="***.*******.*************"
          android:versionCode="7"
          android:versionName="1.5">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT #2**

After a little bit of digging it seems like there is a problem with the dex2oat trying to create oat file:

```
dex2oat : Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@***.*******.*************-2@base.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
```

I have no idea what to do now.
Referenced libraries: Google Play Services and Android Support v13.
If I remove the libraries the project works fine... so what is the problem?

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: I am not using gradle or android studio. the project is written on the netbeans framework. I can show the AndroidManifest.xml if you need.

Comment: Any thoughts???

Comment: Clean your project

Comment: Tried cleaning and rebuilding... still no success

Comment: If you need I can post the libs' manifest file

Comment: after a bit of digging I found out this is some dex2oat issue... check out the edit

Comment: When I remove the libraries the app works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after a long time of searching it turns out the problem was with the sdk manager of android - I downloaded all the build tools when I only had to download one.
So I deleted all the unnecessary packages and the project is now working fine.
Thanks for those who tried to help!

Comment: I've found myself in the same problem when I've tried to run a debug .apk file on physical device instead of Android Studio's emulator... looks like the answer works in this scenario too... :)

Answer (score 3):

My such problem was solved by:- 1)Clean 2) Build --> Build Apk. And this Apk was working fine earlier i was just coping from app->build->output->apk.